# How to write a lambda function that is conditional on two variables (columns) in python

Tags: python, lambda, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a data set, df, with two variables, x and y. I want to write a function that does the following:

> x if x>100 and y<50 else y

I am used to doing data analysis in STATA so I'm relatively new to pandas for data analysis. If it helps, in stata it would look like:

> replace x = cond(x>100 & y<50, x, y)

In other words, the function is conditional on two columns in df and will return a value from one variable or the other in each row depending on whether the condition is met.

So far I have been creating new variables through new functions like:

> df.dummyVar = df.x.apply(lambda x: 1 if x>100 else 0)

Using StackOverflow and the documentation I have only been able to find how to apply a function dependent on a single variable to more than one column (using the axis option). Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `where`:

```
df['dummyVar '] = df['x'].where((df['x'] > 100) & (df['y'] < 50), df['y'])
```

This will be much faster than performing an apply operation as it is vectorised.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. And this is great because I can already see how I can expand it to conditionals on 3 or more variables. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
f = lambda x, y: x if x>100 and y<50 else y
```

Lambda(s) in Python are equivalent to a normal function definition.

```
def f(x, y):
    return x if x>100 and y<50 else y
```

**NB:** The body of a Lambda must be a valid expression. This means you cannot use things like: `return` for example; a Lambda will return the last expression evaluated.

For some good reading see:

- [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)
- [Lambdas](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: I had actually written a function like this but was unable to implement so that it would run through each row without a loop. The answer provided by EdChum does exactly that. If you know of a way to accomplish that using this defined function I'm sure I could make use of that in the future. Thank you for you input :)

Comment: @seeiespi You originally asked for "How to create a lambda function that takes two arguments?" -- This is how :) -- EdChum provided you with an answer that is more aligned with what you're intentions are/were with your dataset(s) and pandas.

Answer (score 2):

There's now an pretty easy way to do this. Just use apply on the dataset:

```
df['dummy'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['x'] if row['x'] > 100 and row['y'] < 50 else row['y'])
```

Comment: I need to write the axis = 1 to make it work